# Is using google maps for android SDK in China working? Any Solution for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

Is using google maps for android SDK in China working?
I've been trying by VPN and it's not working.

Is there some SDK setting I'm missing? 
Like the javascript api allows change the url to

```
 http://maps.google.cn/
```

If not, can anyone give me some suggestion?
I've been trying the `Skobbler` OSM Maps, the speed of randomly loading when loading the world wide map area is so slow.

Does it works by using the `webview` (Google map javascript API) ?

Our app need to show the global countries map, including China area.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the google maps to GaoDe (amap).

First because Google maps need the googles services, which are not available on Chinese phones.

Then because if there is a way with JavaScript to get to the Chinese google map ( see the following link: developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#china_ws_access ), for android with java it is still not reliable.

Comment: Can We set the labels to english in AMAP/GaoDe Map